# How do I unlock the pier in CityVille?

Tags: cityville

How to unlock pier in cityville?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.gameguidecentral.com/2010/12/02/cityville-quests-list/) has a list of all the quests and what you need to do to complete them.  The Pier is near the middle of the "tree", right after build a school.  It requires you to have 3 expansions and lay 3 roads.

[The Zynga forums](http://forums.zynga.com/showthread.php?t=1124406&page=61) have a huge thread about this particular quest not unlocking for people.  The solution that is offered again and again is to clear up other quests that you have been assigned.  Apparently there is a limit to the number of quests you can be assigned at one time, which means the Pier quest (or one of the ones leading up to it) might be blocked.  So if you haven't seen the quest yet, just keep working on other ones you have and it should eventually show up.

Comment: There's another expansion called The New Seaport, which requires you to have 3 Expansions & lay 3 Roads, and also to have unlocked the Pier. But what can I do if the pier isn't unlocking? I have already the Seaport, 6 Expansions, 20 Roads ... but still the Pier is locked!

Comment: @Spider Have you completed all the tasks that are higher up in the tree?

Comment: Hey, are you sure this information is still current? We're getting [quite the negative anonymous feedback on this answer...](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/least-helpful?filter=all)

Comment: Hav completed the the new seaport quest, also the higher-up quests, done all mentioned in different zynga support forums like clear cache and things like that but THE PIER IS STILL UNLOCKING Secondly, when i receive tiles for the COMMUNITY POOL from my friends, they dont show up in my inventory and the pool shows 0/8 tiles.... Totally messed up thing :(

Comment: @Zeeshan Yah, I don't actually play this game, but all the forum posts certainly make one think that there is some bug involved (or at least some really terrible game design).